# Angular $promise without using defer

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

Everything on the net about promises these days says don't use defer when using promises except docs/examples on angular.js.

What is the proper way to return the value of an angular.js $promise without using defer?

Here's what I currently have:

```
function foo() {
  var deferred = $q.defer();    
  userService.findProgramsByUser({personId: personId}).$promise
    .then(function (programs) {
        deferred.resolve(programs);
    });
  return deferred.promise;
}
```

If i was using the node Q library I would do this:

```
function foo() {
  return Q.promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    userService.findProgramsByUser({personId: personId})
      .then(function (programs) {
        resolve(programs);
      });
  }
}
```

How can I do something similar with an angular promise without having to use defer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `userService.findProgramsByUser()` already has a promise property, just return that

```
function foo() {          
  return userService.findProgramsByUser({personId: personId}).$promise
     .then(function (programs) {
          return programs;
     }, function(){
        // handle errors
     });        
}
```

Comment: What if i want to potentially return the rejection though?

Comment: can use `then` with both callback arguments and return the data within the first argument -- or handle the rejection at the other end.

Comment: The calling code receives the promise itself and can interact with it directly. What you were originally attempting was only wrapping an existing promise in a new promise.

Comment: Ahh i think you're right. No need for me to wrap that.

Comment: I would say the original code is still the better way because it allows you to decouple your controller/ui code from your backend. With the one in the answer if anything changes in the backend it might end up affecting a lot of your code.

Comment: Actually what i'm trying to do is when a value is returned from userService.findProgramByUser, I perform some logic and then return that value. So i don't actually want to return the value that directly comes back from userService.findProgramsByUser. I just stripped that logic out for simplicity

Comment: Both callbacks is considered an anti-pattern. http://www.datchley.name/promise-patterns-anti-patterns/ . Should use `.then()` and `.catch()`

Comment: @Catfish see update with adding `then` ...switch to catch if you prefer

Comment: The key was just returning my value in the `.then/.catch` function as well as returning the entire method call. With Q.promise I actually define a method with a `resolve/reject` function.

Answer (score 1):

I really don't understand why it's bad to use defer. In most cases my services looks like:

```
var defers = {}; //somewhere in the service root.

getData: function(id){

    var defKey = 'getData' + id;

    if(defers.hasOwnProperty(defKey)) return defers[defKey].promise;

    //here is a good spot to return something from custom cache

    defers[defKey] = $q.defer();

    serverApiRequest('/api/...').then(function(response){
        defers[defKey].resolve(response.data);
        delete defers[defKey];
    });

    return defers[defKey].promise;

}
```

Deferred promises are awesome. With such approach we can be 100% sure that server will be requested only one time and every parallel requests would be served.